# How to get an image from Azure Blob Storage via web api as binary?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, azure-blob-storage

I have a webapi method so that users can upload their own profile picture, however in my entity  which is saved in CosmosDB I save the profile picture URL.

```
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateSuperAdministrator(SuperAdministrator superadministrator)
        {
            var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
            try
            {
                var superAdministratorStore = CosmosStoreHolder.Instance.CosmosStoreSuperAdministrator;
                //First we validate the model
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }

                //Then we validate the content type
                if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
                }

                //Initalize configuration settings
                var accountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storage:account:name"];
                var accountKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storage:account:key"];
                var profilepicturecontainername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storage:account:profilepicscontainername"];

                //Instance objects needed to store the files
                var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer imagesContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(profilepicturecontainername);
                var provider = new AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(imagesContainer);

                foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
                {

                    var fileName = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"').Trim();
                    if (fileName.EndsWith(".png"))
                    {
                        var img = Image.FromFile(file.LocalFileName);
                        if (img.Width != 200 && img.Height != 200)
                        {
                            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                            return BadRequest($"Error Lulo. Unsupported extension, only PNG is valid. Or unsuported image dimensions (200px x 200px)");
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Try to upload file
                try
                {
                    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    var dt = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "Error Lulo: ", guid }
                    };
                    telemetry.TrackException(ex, dt);
                    return BadRequest($"Error Lulo. An error has occured. Details: {guid} {ex.Message}: ");
                }

                // Retrieve the filename of the file you have uploaded
                var filename = provider.FileData.FirstOrDefault()?.LocalFileName;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
                {
                    string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    var dt = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "Error Lulo: ", guid }
                    };

                    return BadRequest($"Error Lulo. An error has occured while uploading your file. Please try again.: {guid} ");
                }

                //Rename file
                CloudBlockBlob blobCopy = imagesContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(superadministrator.Id + ".png");
                if (!await blobCopy.ExistsAsync())
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob blob = imagesContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

                    if (await blob.ExistsAsync())
                    {
                        await blobCopy.StartCopyAsync(blob);
                        await blob.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
                    }
                }

                superadministrator.ProfilePictureUrl = blobCopy.Name;

                var result = await superAdministratorStore.UpdateAsync(superadministrator);
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var dt = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Error Lulo: ", guid }
                };

                telemetry.TrackException(ex, dt);
                return BadRequest("Error Lulo: " + guid);
            }            
        }
```

Now my question is about the endpoind GET.  Because the profile picture needs to be shown in the navigation bar on the app, I need to get it in binary format, if that makes sense?
In other words, I cant return the ProfilePicture URL to the client (a React App), because its a client app which does not have access to the blob storage.

Here is my get.

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetSuperAdministrator(string email)
        {
            var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
            try
            {
                var superAdministratorStore = CosmosStoreHolder.Instance.CosmosStoreSuperAdministrator;

                var superadministrator = await superAdministratorStore.Query().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.EmailAddress == email);
                if (superadministrator == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                return Ok(superadministrator);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var dt = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Error Lulo: ", guid }
                };

                telemetry.TrackException(ex, dt);
                return BadRequest("Error Lulo: " + guid);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on my knowledge, you React App will show a html page, which means that there will be a html `<img src="url">` in the html.  Then the browser will try to get the image from the url.

So, there would be 2 optional solutions:

1.Generate a storage blob url with SAS, and set it as the image's url in `<img>`.  With SAS, a clinet will be able to access the image from storage directly.

2.The url would be the request path of yout Web API. For example: `/image/{image_name}`. And your web api will return a image:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetImage()
{           
    // Get the image blob
    CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = ********;
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStream(ms);
        return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

---

Update:

My code:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    string connString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storagetest789;AccountKey=G36mcmEthM****=;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
    CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("pub");
    CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("p033tw9j.jpg");

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStream(ms);
        return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: are you sure about last line?, I get this.
Error CS1955 Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Sorry, I just tested in a web application project.  There is a File method in Controller class.  As you are using web api, you need to `return new FileContentResult(....)`